# Replace php echo output with certain variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, str-replace

I have a mysql data table with "itemLevels" (numbers). So if i echo the itemlevels out i want that they get replaced with a certain text.

itemLevels 1 => Text1; itemLevels 2 => Text2; itemLevels => Text3

At the moment i have the following code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","XXXXXX","XXXXX","XXXXX");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }



/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
} else {

}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE name=test";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());

echo "<table>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name= $row['name'];
    $itemLevel= $row['itemLevel'];


    echo
"<tr><td class='name'>".$name."</td></tr>
<tr><td class='name'>Gegenstandsstufe ".$itemLevel."</td></tr> 
</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I´ve read about "php str_replace" but im not sure if it is the right idea and how to use it in my code.

Comment: Yes , use str_replace string function. See this manual: -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an array

```
$itemLevelNames = [
    0 => 'Text0',
    1 => 'Text1',
    2 => 'Text2',
    42 => 'Text42',
    // and so on
];
```

And then output the text via

```
echo $itemLevelNames[$itemLevel];
```

Comment: Where do i put in the array?  Inside the while loop?

Comment: @Hertus No, you can put it outside of the loop, because – I assume – the names of the item levels don’t change inside the loop.